Flutter not updating when tab changes
I want to make an app with flutter ;
When i change the tab , my app still showing first data.
I delete data from firestore ; but app still show the first data .
This is my firestore codes:
var l=[];
 Future<Object?> getdata() async {
    final docSnap = await users.where("becais", isEqualTo: true).get();
    final allData = docSnap.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    setState(() {
      l = allData;
      print(l);
    });
return allData;
  }

This is my tabbar codes:
home:DefaultTabController(length: 3,child:Scaffold(
         drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: true,
         drawer: const Drawer(),
         appBar: AppBar(
             bottom:  const TabBar(

               tabs: [
                 Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                 Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                 Tab(icon:Icon(Icons.code))
               ]
             )
..............

And this is my Futurebuilder code:
body: FutureBuilder(
        future:getdata(),
        builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasData) {
return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
}
............

I try this :
Sometimes work , somtimes dont work :)
 tabs: [
                 Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                 Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                 Tab(child:IconButton(onPressed: getdata,
                 icon: const Icon(Icons.code))

               ]


Why you are using l array list and also setstate explain
